# Spark Dataframe Repartioning Causing uneven paritions

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

I am using spark `repartition` to change the number of partitions in the `dataframe`.

While writing the data after repartitioning I saw there are different size parquet files have been created.

Here is the code which I am using to repartition

`df.repartition(partitionCount).write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).parquet("/test")`

Most of the partitions in size KBs and some of them is in around 100MB which is the size I want to keep per partition.

Here is a sample

```
20.2 K  /test/part-00010-0957f5aa-1f14-4295-abe2-0aacfe135444.snappy.parquet
20.2 K  /test/part-00011-0957f5aa-1f14-4295-abe2-0aacfe135444.snappy.parquet
99.9 M  /test/part-00012-0957f5aa-1f14-4295-abe2-0aacfe135444.snappy.parquet
```

Now if I open the `20.2K parquet` files and do a `coun`t action the result comes to be `0`. For `99.9M file` the same `count` operation gives some non zero result.

Now as per my understanding of `repartition` in `dataframe`, it does a full shuffle and tries to keep each partition of same size. However the above mentioned example contradicts that.

Could someone please help me here.

Comment: Please post the code you use to repartition and execution plan ([How to make good reproducible Apache Spark Dataframe examples](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48427185/8371915))

Comment: I have added the code. I don't think that is a necessity here. Repartition is a simple function call. Also it is not some dataframe manipulation problem. It needs spark theoretical explanation.

Comment: I feel your pain. Did you ever solve your problem?

Comment: No, I could not find a way to fix this.